# How do I segmentate dirty 7-seg LCD with reflections

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The LCD display cannot be cleaned, the light conditions cannot be changed and the background can be tricky. So, I cannot use any kind of segmentation by color, search for rectangles and use Otsu. MSER doesn't give a good result. I even tried to locate display relatively to "DEXP" logo. The logo turned out to be too small to do this with sufficient accuracy. Bilateral filtering or gaussian blur helps, but not much. Even supposing that I found ROI, local thresholding gives too noisy results. Morphological transformations don't help. Is there a way to extract digits for further OCR?
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Locating dexp logo and the 2 icons on bottom would be my approach, followed by homography transformations

Comment: any low level processing is futile. tesseract also won't work here. you need deep learning. or get a scale with wifi/bluetooth or a serial port. that's probably cheaper than spending time engineering a computer vision solution. even if you use this to teach yourself, it's opening up a huge can of worms.